# NFS mount on LXC container

Tags: lxc, proxmox

I have been testing NFS mounts on LXC containers and they work mostly ok after you have modified App-Armour settings on the host. Problems arise when the LXC containers are moved or host-node restarts.
LXC container does not always seem to honor the `/etc/fstab` settings which results in mounts not working which results in Apache and email braking down because they are stored on NFS share somewhere else.

My fstab contains:

```
10.10.20.20:/Q1vmail  /var/vmail  nfs  auto,noatime,nolock,bg,nfsvers=3,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800  0 0
```

I'm wondering what kind of solutions you are familiar with to combat this problem?

How can I automate a "test" that checks if NFS share is mounted and if it's not then tries "mount -a" again?

Comment: This is in my fstab: 10.10.20.20:/Q1vmail      /var/vmail      nfs     auto,noatime,nolock,bg,nfsvers=3,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800  0 0

Comment: `stat -f -c %T /var/vmail`